# Cannot boot ubuntu after fresh install

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, grub-efi, gpt

I am new to Ubuntu. I have erased windows and installed Ubuntu 20.04. But after installation I am not able to boot. In BIOS I can see Ubuntu option but when I click nothing happens.
I am using ASUS F571 - UEFI system with GPT disk partitions. I have tried to repair GRUB from Live Ubuntu USB disk but nothing happens. Can somebody please help.

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 20. There is a 20.04 and a 20.10

Comment: What happens exactly when you try booting Ubuntu?

Comment: be patient it will work ...  every hardware setup is different ... during ubuntu install it probes hardware and tries its best to adapt its settings though sometimes it needs some hand holding ...  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair   is the tool of choice ... boot into liveUSB and get online to install it ... post the URL it gives you on finishing so others can lend a hand

Comment: @David It is Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: "nothing happens" is too vague. It's likely that *something* happens: A flicker, a change of screen, a beep, disk activity, fan speed change. If GRUB fails to acknowledge any keypress at all, check that your keyboard is properly connected.

Comment: Ubuntu 20?  There is no such release. Ubuntu uses *yy.mm* format (year.month of release) for all server & desktop releases, the *yy* being used only for IoT and specialist appliance/device releases (also suitable for cloud use) that can use *snap* packages only.  By Ubuntu 20 you imply Ubuntu Core 20, a different product to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, so please correct your question.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Asus BIOS utility page stays as it is

Comment: @ScottStensland Yes I understand, I have tried Boot-Repair tool and also tried to update grub. I have followed all the methods in [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows). Now the problem is I don't have neither windows nor ubuntu running on my system. 
I'll post the URL I get from boot-repair

Comment: @ScottStensland Here is the link I got after boot-repair. Please help
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/2kTyVr7f4D/

Comment: UEFI settings > Boot... Make sure "Ubuntu" is selected. That should be all. Your Boot Repair info clearly states the boot order as the USB flash (because you're booting from it) followed by Windows (the now non-existing OS that still has .efi files in the ESP).

Comment: @ChanganAuto In boot priority Ubuntu is there [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nZJ0Y5i6b1TO04vFd2au2HLdkjlS7oq5/view?usp=drivesdk) but when I open Boot menu, it is empty [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12kgCWAMvGtJc4pLdKFfGBz_gZO9uNx8Y/view?usp=drivesdk). I have attached images in the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing the same issue. While installing instead of selecting "Something else", I selected "Erase everything" and that worked for me.